# How to change native splash screen with Javascript splash screen?

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I need that when the native splash screen finishes loading, another splash screen (now on the javascript side) continues loading... with the same image and the same size shown on the native splash screen.

I already tried to define some sizes and positions on screen. But they never look alike. Can anyone point me to some documentation for me to study or guide me on how I can do this?

Comment: You can try expo-splash-screen package if you are on expo. Or may be there's some other package like react native splash screen (haven't used) which can help you to keep splash screen up and hide when needed.

Comment: can you add screenshots of difference?

Answer (score 0):

Technically splash screen is a part of the native application. You can't modify it from React Native side.

However, using libraries like https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash you can control when to hide the splash screen. For example:

```js
const App = () => {
  componentDidMount() {
    // do your logic even async
    RNBootSplash.hide(); // call it to hide native splash screen
  }
}
```

Comment: This I understood, what I need now is to create another splash screen similar to the native one, on the React Native side. What I can't do is leave the logo the same size and same alignment. for the user it has to look like it's the same screen

Comment: @LayTexas it means you need to show another content between the native splash screen and the same splash screen on js side?

Comment: exactly. I need to show the same screen. I just need to add one more component on the screen on the javascript side (one loading)